# Using value returned by a method as input parameter in C#

Tags: c#, return-value, input-parameters

I have a method returnNo in C# that returns a string as shown below.

```
public string RecordNo()
{
    //Get the string of the Record No from the page
    string recordSavedNumber = recordNoForRecord.Text.Replace("- Record #", "");
    return recordSavedNumber;
}
```

I also want to use the recordSavedNumber returned by the method above as input parameter in a searchMethod show below

```
public void searchRecord(string recordNum){
// do something
}
```

Can someone please assist how I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
 var num = RecordNo();
 searchRecord(num);
```

or like this:

```
searchRecord(RecordNo());
```

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn i suspect there is more to it that this simple answer tho, seems too easy

Comment: Thanks. The first one is the one that worked